# How to make duplicates of my nodes in current linked list?

Tags: java, while-loop, linked-list, nodes

I am having difficulty coming up with a solution to my homework assignment. My professor gave me a bunch of test linked lists and wants me to duplicate each node present in the linked list.

Example:

```
    int[] array = {1, 2, 3, 4, 10};
    LinkedIntList list = new LinkedIntList(array);
    list.stutter();
```

The outcome when I print out my new list should be: {1, 1, 2, 2, 3, 3, 4, 4, 10, 10}

Here is what I have so far... (I can't think of a reasonable while loop)

```
public void stutter(){

    if (front == null) {
        return;
    }
    ListNode current = front;
    while (current.next != null) {
        if (current != null) {
            ListNode duplicate = new ListNode(current.data, current.next);
            current.next = duplicate;

        } 
        current = current.next;
    }
}
```

I also have a lot of constructors, but since I summon one in my method, here is the relevant constructor:

```
public ListNode(int data, ListNode next){
    this.data = data;
    this.next = next;
}
```

Any help is appreciated!!!

Comment: Your current code will fail to `stutter` a list of just one element

Comment: hence the reason why I need assistance @smac89

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You just have to make sure to point to the `next` of the duplicate rather than `current.next`:

```
public void stutter() {
    for (ListNode current = front; current != null; ) {
        ListNode duplicate = new ListNode(current.data, current.next);
        current.next = duplicate;
        current = duplicate.next
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you! You are a life saver

Comment: @theNoobJavaCoder as long as you understand why I did the things I did in there, not a problem. Gl

Answer (score 0):

try this one

```
public Node reverse(){

    Node p= this;
    Node firstDuplicate = new Node(p.getItem()); //save reference for first node to return
    Node currentDuplicate=firstDuplicate;

    while(Node.NIL!=p.getNext()){
        Node nextNode = p.getNext();
        Node nextCopy = new Node(nextNode.getItem());
        currentDuplicate.n = nextCopy;
        currentDuplicate = nextCopy;
        p = nextNode;
    }


          /* If the list is empty */
          if(firstDuplicate == NIL)
              return Node.NIL;

          /* If the list has only one node */
          if(firstDuplicate.n == Node.NIL)
              return firstDuplicate;

         // Node reverseRest = new Node(p.getItem(),Node.NIL);
          Node rest = new Node(); 
          rest = firstDuplicate.getNext();

          firstDuplicate.setNext(Node.NIL); 
         // Node reverseRest=new Node(p.getItem(),reverseRest);

         Node reverseRest=new Node();
           reverseRest = rest.reverse();

          /* Join the two lists */
          rest.setNext(firstDuplicate); 
          //p=this;
        //  p=p.nthNext(0);
          return reverseRest;
      }
```